# Problema con Rest API Sinch en PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

soy muy nuevo usando cURL en PHP, quisiera usar esta API para enviar SMS pero cuando hago todas las pruebas me sale el siguiente error:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Length: 0 X-Application-Context: application:production:8080

He revisado mi código y no entiendo que esta pasando realmente:

```
$data=array('from' => '506712xxxx', 'to' => '50671xxxx', 'body' => 'Hola este es un mensaje de prueba' );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sms.api.sinch.com/xms/v1/xxxxx/batches");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
  ));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($res);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

He revisado la documentación oficial y no se que estoy haciendo mal, la documentación oficial:
https://www.sinch.com/docs/sms/http-rest.html

Comment: no se ve mal el código, has probado con el comando curl como te muestra la documentación ?

Comment: No se como lo haria, gracias Mauricio por responder

Comment: Hay algunos REST Api Client .. algunos se ejecutan desde el Chrome y quizas puedan servirte  . El error 400 es, segpun la documentación, un problema en los datos que envías si mal no entiendo .. Quizas te este faltando algun Token de seguridad o similar..

Comment: Si el token esta en la línea `"Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx",` que no muestro por seguridad. y en el link esta el usuario, gracias por el comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el código final:

```
<?
$data=array('from' => 'Oso', 'to' => array('57xx'), 'body' => 'Hola este es un mensaje de prueba' );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sms.api.sinch.com/xms/v1/xxxx/batches");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
  ));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($res);
//var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

-agregue un  array() adicional en "to"
-convertí a Json con la función json_encode
-Posdata: Las "xxx" eran la llave y el numero de cuenta